# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.1.3.core.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/supersized.core.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:light,regular&v1' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $.supersized({
            //Background image
            slides  :  [ { image : 'images/pendulumWeb.jpg' } ]                 
        });

        $("form[name=emailSubmit]").validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true
                },
                fName: {
                    required: true
                },
                lName: {
                    required: true
                },
                profession: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                title: {
                    required: "Please enter your title."
                },
                fName: {
                    required: "Please enter your first name"
                },
                lName: {
                    required: "Please enter your last name."
                },
                profession: {
                    required: "Please enter your profession"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email"
                }
            }
        });
```

```
<div id="contact">
    <form id="emailSubmit" name="emailSubmit" method="post">
        <legend>Enter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter Information</legend>
        <div id="submit">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">Title</span></td>
                    <td><input id="title" name="title" value="" size="5" max="3" type="text" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">First Name</span></td>
                    <td><input id="fName" name="fName" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">Last Name</span></td>
                    <td><input id="lName" name="lName" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">Profession</span> </td>
                    <td><input id="profession" name="profession" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">Email</span> </td>
                    <td><input id="email" name="email" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">Phone</span></td>
                    <td><input id="phone" name="phone" value="" size="20" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="formTitles">Message</span></td>
                    <td><input id="message" name="message" value="" size="20" type="textarea" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    

            <button class="buttonPositive" type="submit"> Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    </div>

    <div class="success" style="display: none;">
    </div>
```

I keep getting this error in developer tools

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method validate

Here is my code..could one of my external js files be causing this? Stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't see anything like this:

```
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in your HTML so you're probably not pulling in the [form validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) at all. Without that, jQuery won't have a `validate` method so you'll get your "no method validate" error. You will, of course, have to use the right path to `jquery.validate.js` for your site.

Comment: I just assumed that the validator method was in the jquery library. Thanks for the help. I downloaded the plugin and it works now.